# Detect Message "hi" without detecting him or dfahi

Tags: c#

I made a bot with Discord.net.
I have http://www.hastebin.com/uyeveqoxur.avrasm
It detects everything with "hi containing"
I tryed everything like
http://pastebin.com/4wVajZ8u

```
var msg = e.Message.Text.ToLower().Replace("!", " ").Replace("?", " ").Replace(".", " ").Replace(",", "");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) class with this pattern `\bhi\b` *(`\b` is for word boundary)*

Sample example :

```
// need this somewhere at top of file/namespace (or to qualify fully members)
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var rgx = new Regex(@"\bhi\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
var samples = new [] { "Hi someone !", "HI!", "him", "dfahi" };

foreach (var sample in samples)
    Console.WriteLine ($"{sample}, Matched : {rgx.IsMatch(sample)}");
```

> ### Output
>
> Hi someone !, Matched : true
>   HI!, Matched : true
>   him, Matched : false
>   dfahi, Matched : false

Comment: so I use 'if(rgx.IsMatch(sample)){ sending message code }'?

Comment: Yes, if the if test passed it means the given text (content of sample here) is valid (contains "hi" as a word) so inside the corresponding block you do whatever you want to do when the input has the format you expected :-)

Comment: So I need to write every variation in the array?

Comment: Every variation of what ? your question was only about searching "hi" nothing more

Comment: @ChristianProschek you forget to include `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` at top of file/namespace as stated in the message (or what I can understand of it becuase I don't speak german despite my nickname)